# how to manage laravel big update methods

Tags: php, laravel

i have an update method like below which is so big and i want to manage it some how that in take less place in controller and make controller much cleaner now i want to know if there is any way to make it as service or some thing this is my update method for example :

```
      public function update(Request $request, Something $something)
    {

        $something->somefield = $request->get('field1');
        $something->somefield = $request->get('field1');
        $something->somefield = $request->get('field1');
        $something->somefield = $request->get('field1');
        $something->save();
    return response()->json($something, 200);

  //consider i may have like 20 fields here
```

Comment: `$something->update($request->all());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `update()` method to update all fields

```
public function update(Request $request, Something $something)
{

        $something->update($request->all());
        return response()->json($something, 200);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the appropriate way to do this is to name the *input* fields of the form and fields of the table same. Then you can just use `$something->update($request->all());`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in case fields not present in db passed.

```
$something->update($request->only($field1, $field2));
```

Comment: also can use `$something->update($request->except($notDatabaseField))`, in case the number of local fields (not present in database fields) less than the database fields.